# Save stop-Process error in a variable and write it in eventlog

Tags: powershell

This seemed like easy one, but it wasn't.
I have the following function that stops processes and write in eventlog:

```
$PiEventlog = "Company Name"
$PiEventlogSource = "Source Name"
#   For Testing purpose, i use this PIDs.
$gpid = 45852,5264
        
function Terminate-Processs {
#   if $pid is empty, give this msg.
    if(!$gpid){
        Write-Host "Nth here"
    }
    else{
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt ($gpid).Count; $i++) {     
            $PIDForEventLog = $gpid        
            try{
                Stop-Process -Id $gpid[$i] -force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable $ResultStopProcess
                Write-EventLog -logname $PiEventlog -source $PiEventlogSource -eventID 1021 -entrytype Information -message "$env:USERNAME killed the following PID $PIDForEventLog from the instance  $Global:SelectedInstance"
            }
            catch{
                Write-EventLog -logname $PiEventlog -source $PiEventlogSource -eventID 1021 -entrytype Error -message "$env:USERNAME could not kill the following PID $PIDForEventLog from the instance  $Global:SelectedInstance `n$ResultStopProcess `nPlease check manually whether the process is still available."
            }     
        }
    }
}
```

in the Catch loop, i am trying to give the errorvariable $resultstopprcess to the eventlog entry. That means, if an error occur while stoping an process, the error should be saved into that variable and it should be given to eventlog. the variable should contain sth like this, if error occurs:

> Stop-Process : Es kann kein Prozess mit der Prozess-ID 34234 gefunden
> werden. In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
>
> - Stop-Process -id 34234
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (34234:Int32) [Stop-Process], ProcessCommandException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoProcessFoundForGivenId,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopProcessCommand
>   ```

But the variable is somehow always empty.
How can i do this? How can i save the error to a variable. so that i can use it later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Error Analysis

> ```
>  -ErrorVariable $ResultStopProcess
> ```

The parameter `ErrorVariabe` expects the name of the variable without `$` prefix.

> ```
>   try {} catch {}
> ```

With `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`, the catch block will never be entered.

Possible solutions:

- Pass `-ErrorAction Stop` to throw an exception in case of any error
- Keep `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` and check the automatic [execution status variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables#section-1) `$?` for success.

> ```
>   Write-EventLog -message ".... $ResultStopProcess ..."
> ```

This only outputs the exception message ("Es kann kein Prozess mit der Prozess-ID 34234 gefunden werden.").

To include everything you normally see on the console, pass `$ResultStopProcess` to the [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) command.

## Fixed code

```
Stop-Process -Id $gpid[$i] -force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable ResultStopProcess
if( $? ) {
    Write-EventLog -logname $PiEventlog -source $PiEventlogSource -eventID 1021 -entrytype Information -message "$env:USERNAME killed the following PID $PIDForEventLog from the instance  $Global:SelectedInstance"
}
else {
    $ErrorView = 'NormalView'   # PS 7.2+ defaults to 'ConciseView'
    $fullErrorMessage = $ResultStopProcess | Out-String

    Write-EventLog -logname $PiEventlog -source $PiEventlogSource -eventID 1021 -entrytype Error -message "$env:USERNAME could not kill the following PID $PIDForEventLog from the instance  $Global:SelectedInstance `n$fullErrorMessage `nPlease check manually whether the process is still available."
}
```

## Remarks

- Make sure to check `$?` immediately after the command that could possibly fail, else it could be overwritten by another command.
- As of PowerShell 7.2, you don't get the full error message, even when using `Out-String`, as the default formatting mode is now `ConciseView`. Therefore I've set the [preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables#errorview) `$ErrorView = 'NormalView'` to get the same output as in previous PS versions.

Comment: i think you misunderstood my question. I want to be able to give the whole error msg to the event log. for instance the following:
Stop-Process : Es kann kein Prozess mit der Prozess-ID 34234 gefunden werden.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ Stop-Process -id 34234
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (34234:Int32) [Stop-Process], ProcessCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoProcessFoundForGivenId,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopProcessCommand

Comment: cool that works. I actually found another variation, but your answer is much better than what i've found out. Thank you.